# Apache isis sql query not working in isisJdoSupport.executeUpdate()

Tags: isis

I am creating a project using Apache Isis. I need to run an update query in the project using `isisJdoSupport.executeUpdate()`. But it is not updating the value in database. The method returns number of rows updated, but it does not update values in database. I tried running query directly in MySQL and it works, but it does not work with `isisJdoSupport.executeUpdate()`. Is there a way to make update query work using Apache Isis?

Comment: could you provide an example app demonstrating the issue, up on github, please?  You might also try calling isisJdoSupport.getPersistenceManager().flush() to flush any pending transactions ... perhaps that's the issue?